# Angular material doesn't dialog scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material, responsive

I use the material dialog that contains number input. in the mobile view, I can't scroll the dialog content when the keyboard is open so I can't see the input number. what should I do?

**the number input is under the keyboard and 
I can't see what typing is possible**. please help me

Comment: How are you compiling your project for Android and which keyboard are you using, native or a custom one ?

Comment: I don't compile. it is just responsive with pure CSS. I just do it with angular and responsive it with pure CSS

Comment: Well if you have position absolute for your keyboard, then it would definitely not scroll but this is nothing to do with material dialog and scrolling. You would need to provide some code for your implementation.

Comment: I don't add position to keyboard its default mode of phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding some class when the material dialog was open

**html**:

```
<div class="parent-container" [class.noscroll]="openOverlay == true">
   ...........
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.noscroll {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  pointer-events: auto !important; // be able to scroll event
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  align-items: start !important;  // not center the dialog
  z-index: auto !important; // remove z-index
}
.cdk-overlay-pane {
  margin: 1rem; //enter code here
  z-index: 1002; // over the overlay
}
```